# Compare storing the numerator and the denominator of a fraction

Tags: c++, fractions

I want to compare the storing in the computer memory the numerator and the denominator of a fraction as two unsigned integers and a separate Boolean variable representing the sign with storing the numerator and denominator as signed integers. On the basic example of addition, subtraction, division and multiplication of two fractions. Which option in your opinion of storing is preferable? Might it be better to add a Boolean variable representing the sign of the fraction?

Comment: I'd probably go with something like `struct Fraction { bool sign; unsigned int numerator; unsigned int denominator; };` But that's only my opinion, and such questions are _off-topic_ here.

Comment: Because of alignment requirements, adding a `bool` will probably increase your `struct`'s effective memory footprint by a lot more than you expect. It will probably act as-if it contained 3 `unsigned int` in terms of how much padding it will need. Edit : Not to mention the added complexity of having to check the sign all the time.

Comment: If the size determinant to not add a _bool_ because it will probably increase the size as an _int_, 50% more. But out of that difficult to guess if it more practical to have the sign out of the 2 numbers or to have it on the numerator for instance, just write the 4 operations following the two solutions and you will know better ;-)

Comment: _@Michal_ You might find the [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) class useful for solving your problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::ratio` only has one value per instantiation, and isn't normalised

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/rational/rational.html) is a good example of how to implement this. If you template it on an unsigned integer type, then it will underflow for negative numbers.

As noted in the Boost documentation:

"When used with a limited precision integer type, the rational class suffers from many of the precision issues which cause difficulty with floating point types."